# mysql vs redis for dialogs ( chats)?

Tags: mysql, redis

Does it make sense to use redis instead of mysql for many chats? Will there be an increase in speed? I think because of one thread redis speed Vice versa will fall.a

Comment: If you're willing to be a bit bleeding edge (they should hit redis stable any day now) redis streams are a much more natural data type for chat applications, take a look at https://get-reddie.com/blog/building-real-time-chat-with-redis-streams/

Answer (score 0):

Yes , there are following advantages

- Every time the user send data(message) I do not need to open mysql
  connection and store on it. We can save it on redis and use pub/sub
  to broadcast it on real time.
- I can publish all those data and other    clients(javascript/android)
  can subscribe in a real time using    message queue based on redis.
- I can trigger real time alerts(like user gone offline etc)

Since Redis runs in memory, it is very fast but is disk persistent. So in case a crash happens, data is not lost. Redis can perform about 110,000 SETs and about 81,000 GETs per second

Comment: Перевод скопирован
one thread does not affect performance? Does it in onononon this set of operations : zrangebyscore, zremrangebyrank, zadd